# Revenue Cat Error 23 There is an issue with your configuration. Check the underlying error for more details

Tags: ios, flutter, revenuecat

[image: error screenshot]

I get an error like this. This is the code I opened the Paywall screen with:

`Future<void> presentPaywallIfNeeded() async { final paywallResult = await RevenueCatUI.presentPaywallIfNeeded( 'premium_creation', displayCloseButton: true, ); Log.d('Paywall result: $paywallResult'); }`

If anyone has solved this problem, please help me.